Python subprocess.Popen.communicate() does not wait for the process to complete
On Ubuntu 22, using Python 3.10, I need to set up a VPN connection and analyze the response from the VPN server. I do this as follows:
connect_command = ['ip', 'netns', 'exec', 'vpn_test_namespace', 'ipsec', 'up', 'vpn_test_config']
connect_process = subprocess.Popen(connect_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
connect_output, connect_error = connect_process.communicate()

However, the process does not wait for completion, and communicate() executes instantly. As a result, connect_output and connect_error are empty. If I add a pause:
connect_command = ['ip', 'netns', 'exec', 'vpn_test_namespace', 'ipsec', 'up', 'vpn_test_config']
connect_process = subprocess.Popen(connect_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(3)
connect_output, connect_error = connect_process.communicate()

Or wait using a breakpoint, then everything is okay, and I see the result. What am I doing wrong?
I tried various methods recommended on StackOverflow or in Google, such as call(), check_call(), wait(), run(), but I was unable to achieve the desired result of making the script wait for the process to complete.

This is not what I expect. I guess ip is doing something funny, and that this cannot be reproduced with any other commands?

ip netns creates a virtual environment for isolating network traffic, which is called network namespaces. So, in this case, the command "ip netns exec vpn_test_namespace ipsec up vpn_test_config" simply indicates that the VPN should be enabled in a specific namespace named "vpn_test_namespace".

The question is more like, does it perhaps spawn a separate subprocess and then let the parent die before the child has emitted any output, or some shenanigan like that?

It could be like this, perhaps another child process is being created. But if so, how can I wait for all processes to finish, including all child processes? Because if I manually execute a command in the terminal, I clearly see that the input line is not available yet, as the command has not completed. Why can't I determine this using Python code?

If indeed this is what's happening I would look at whether ip could be fixed to not play tricks like that. I don't have a way to repro that here but I can speculate that something like a shell wrapper which runs it in the background and then waits might work.

I doubt that it's possible to "fix" this trick in ip. This is a standard command for executing a command in a specific namespace, there is no other way to execute it. It seems that the problem is that subprocess.Popen does not see new child processes, only one parent process.
